# Emacs ruby-mode indenting customization for case..when and assignment from an if..else?

Tags: ruby, emacs

In Emacs, using ruby-mode, I can't find a way to stop this happening:

```
foo = if something?
        42
      else
        7
      end
```

When our in-house conventions are:

```
foo = if something?
  42
else
  7
end
```

(Same goes for `begin..end` and `case..when`).

Also, while it's less of a nuisance, our convention for `case..when` is to indent each `when`.

```
case whatever
  when foo
    "a"
  when bar
    "b"
  else
    "c"
end
```

I know people generally say you should align the `when` with the `case`, but it's not the convention of our company, so does anybody know how to customize this too?  I can find very little customization for ruby-mode.  The only thing I've really been able to customize is the indentation inside parentheses.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, but given that ruby-mode is written by Matz himself, I just adopted to its conventions in the few cases where it was different from my personal ones. Are your company's rules set in stone or open for discussion?

Comment: They're open for discussion, but I think changing conventions on an already established project, just to adhere to one person's text editor is perhaps not ideal ;)  I may look into what's involved in adding some more config options, such as `ruby-indent-case-when` and `ruby-deep-indent-block-assignment` or something.  Maybe.  Currently I just subconsciously know to use `C-q C-j` to create newlines in places where my indentation would be changed.

Comment: Sure, but if the one person's text editor's Ruby mode was written by Ruby's creator, that could help the argument. Anyway, more config options would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: If you are interested in modifying ruby-mode indentation, check out my example at https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_libs/blob/master/ruby-mode-indent-fix.el

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to customize this. ruby-mode is pretty barebone as far as indentation customizations are concerned and Matz (its original author) is totally adamant in supporting the standard style for case indentation.

Comment: Hmmm. Emacs's C mode lets the user customize the indentation rules by means of the `c-offsets-alist` variable. In my opinion, it really should be an option to do the same in any other language -- for instance, in Ruby, I also prefer the `when`s to be indented two spaces relative to the `case`, just as all other statement lists that end in `end` are.

Answer (score 5):

In Emacs 24.4 and newer, you can set `ruby-align-to-stmt-keywords` to `'(if begin case)`, or simply to `t`, to resolve the first part of your question.

It won't change the indentation offset of `when`, though. That would have to be a different option.