# Emacs ruby mode if expressions indentation

Tags: ruby, emacs, indentation, ruby-mode

Emacs 24 ruby-mode insists on indenting if expressions the following way:

```
    before1 = if params[:before]
            Time.zone.at(params[:before].to_i)
    end
```

Which i find just plain wrong. The expected behavior should be:

```
    before1 = if params[:before]
      Time.zone.at(params[:before].to_i)
    end
```

That is - the if block should be indented by exactly one level relative to the line in which the if expression starts. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Be more explicit about the difference, especially when it is about white characters.

Comment: See my reply to a more comprehensive version of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20733875/615245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you actually meant to say that Emacs aligns the `if` with the `end`, which is actually pretty idiomatic in Ruby (and the style enforced by tools like [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop)). The second indentation style is popular for method class with blocks, but not for expressions like `if/unless/case`.

Currently there is now way to change this behaviour. There are plans to introduce a more flexible indentation scheme in ruby-mode in the future, but that's not going to happen in the next Emacs release.

At any rate - it's not a bug, it's a feature :-)

Answer (score 4):

If your Emacs is recent enough (24.4+) and you're using the SMIE indentation engine (`ruby-use-smie` is non-nil), you can use `ruby-align-to-stmt-keywords`:

```
(add-to-list 'ruby-align-to-stmt-keywords 'if)
```